# How to get the median of a CSV column using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The header of my CSV file is as follows:

```
Last Name, First Name, Student No, A1, A2, A3, A4

Squarepants, Spongebob, 9911991199, 99, 88, 77, 66

Star, Patrick, 9912334456, 11, 22, 33, 44

Tentacles, Squidward, 9913243567, 78, 58, 68, 88
```

For my function, I want to return a list of the assignment (A) medians, in order. And the number of assignments can change, so the function should account for n amount of assignments.

Thank you

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: What output are you expecting from above?

Comment: Output is a list of assignment medians (floats) in the order listed in the given file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about collecting your items in a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and then applying [`statistics.median()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median) on each list of medians:

```
from csv import reader
from statistics import median
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
with open('data.csv') as file:
    csv_reader = reader(file)
    headers = list(map(str.strip, next(csv_reader)))

    for line in csv_reader:
        for col, value in enumerate(map(str.strip, line)):
            data[headers[col]].append(value)

medians = {k: median(map(float, v)) for k, v in data.items() if k.startswith('A')}

print(medians)
```

Which outputs a dictionary of medians:

```
{'A1': 78.0, 'A2': 58.0, 'A3': 68.0, 'A4': 66.0}
```

**UPDATE:**

As requested, you may also get a list of medians like so:

```
print(list(medians.values()))
# [78.0, 58.0, 68.0, 66.0]
```

Comment: thank you, that would work but unfortunately I need a list of floats as an output